# Dead laptop, no indicator, no power, no charging

Tags: laptop

recently my laptop just completely died.
the model is asus m409da-ek502t. for the past 4 years no problem had occured before and my usage was completely normal.
i noticed that i cannot turn it on nor can i charge it 2 days ago. the day before i did use the laptop for hdmi and used it for hours (perhaps that is the cause). i tried unplugging the battery and try to turn the laptop on still no result. same as before zero signs of life.

any suggestion will be very much appreciated.
thanks in advance.